# jayway JsonPath + ruby regexp

Tags: json, regex, jsonpath

i'm almost new to the regular expressions.

I'm writing a JsonPath expression using [jayway](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) and [ruby regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html)
I want to find node by matching only first 2 letters of the book author property

The actual expression

```
$..book[?(@.author =~ /\A.{0}(Ni).*/)]
```

finds what i need

```
[
   {
      "category" : "reference",
      "author" : "Nigel Rees",
      "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
      "price" : 8.95
   }
]
```

from

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
```

}

Do you know more clean regexp for that case? What is unnecessary in or should be added to the actual regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me have a try.

The regex `/\A.{0}(Ni).*/` means:

1. `\A` - Match the beginning of a string
2. `.{0}` - Match any character but a newline exactly 0 times
3. `(Ni)` - Match and capture into group 1 literal text `Ni`
4. `.*` - Match 0 or more characters other than a newline as many as possible

And you just check for a match with `=~`.

The unnecessary parts are Point 1 and 2. Remove `\A` since the expression is anchored by default. Remove the `.{0}` as it makes no sense.

The `.*` seems necessary since the expression should match the entire string. And as a minor improvement, remove the parentheses from `(Ni)` since you are not using any backreferences. Note that it is pointless from the logical point of view to capture/store something we already know with a regex unless there is some specific purpose for that (e.g. splitting a string into an array).

Thus, use

```
$..book[?(@.author =~ /Ni.*/)]
```

Note that adding `/i` modifier makes the expression match values starting with `ni`, too.

Comment: Thank you, but no, '$..book[?(@.author =~ /\ANi/)]' doesn't find anything, you can check the expression [here](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book[?%28@.author%20=~%20/.*REES/i%29])